# Key press event of a dynamically generated textbox

Tags: jquery, dynamic

```
tr.append($("<td/>").html('<input type="text" name="unit_price" id="unit_price"/>'));
```

This is my dynamically generated text box i have tried many solutions like below but its not working help me geeks

```
$("#unit_price").live("keyup", function(){  
     //Your Code to handle the click.
    }); 

$(staticAncestors).on(eventName, dynamicChild, function() {});
```

Comment: `live` is deprecated. See http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this..**

```
<table >
    <tr>
        <td class="test"></td>  

    </tr>
</table>

$(document).ready(function(){

$(".test").append($("<td/>").html('<input type="text" name="unit_price" id="unit_price"/>'));
     $("#unit_price").keyup(function(){
alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

**Demo:**http://jsfiddle.net/cz1dvzvf/1/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**.

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$("body").on("keyup","#unit_price", function(){  
 //Your Code to handle the click.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
$(document).on("keyup","#unit_price", function(){  
 //Results here
});
```